# Como enviar varias funciones de diferentes controladores a una vista en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una vista donde quiero cargar varios datos de diferentes tablas, los tengo en diferentes controladores, como puedo enviar esos datos mediante una ruta a la vista.

```
Route::get('estudiantes',function(){
return view('estudiantes');})->name('estudiantes');
```

Esta es la ruta con la cual ingreso a la vista

Answer (score 0):

Los datos que quieres enviar a una vista deberán estar en un método, ejemplo:

```
public function index(){
    $data1 = Model1::all();
    $data2 = Model2::all();
    return view('estudiantes', [
       'data1' => $data1,
       'data2' => $data2,
    ]);
}
```

Ruta, Archivo `web.php`

> Route::get('estudiantes', 'EstudiantesController@index')->name('estudiantes');

Comment: Si eso lo entiendo pero lo datos son ciudades y departamentos y tengo que cargarlos en la vista de un registro de un estudiante, esos los tengo en CiudadesController y DepartamentosController y necesito que se me carguen cuando entre a la vista de registro del estudiante.

Comment: la vista la estoy cargando asi porque cargo una pagina en un div por medio de jquery

Comment: @JeissonHernandez es el tipo detalle de enviar los departamentos a la vista y según el departamento carguen las ciudades. Esto último se hace con Ajax. ¿Ya lo tiene ? ¿Puede añadir a su pregunta? y especificar qué es lo que desea exactamente. en principio esto responde a lo que se entiende de su pregunta.

Comment: Como puedo cargar en la ruta que tengo  arriba,la funcion que me trae las ciudades y departamentos, los cuales los estoy trayendo de un controlador diferente cada uno.

Comment: lo de ajax si lo se hacer, no tengo problemas con eso

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo necesitas obtener datos de varios modelos en un controlador.

Para ello simplemente llamamos al modelo haciendo uso del `namespace` de dicho modelo.

Por ejemplo

```
public function index(){
    $ciudades = \App\Ciudades::get();
    $departamentos = \App\Departamentos::get();

        return view('estudiantes', [
           'ciudades' => $ciudades,
           'departamentos' => $departamentos,
        ]);
}
```